# Android Setting a ringtone doesn't work on samsung mobiles

Tags: android

I've searched the web and stackoverflow couldn't find anything but this code which I'm using.

My problem that it works on sony xperia U (2.3.3 and 4.0.3) and on xperia neo v(2.3.3 and 4.0.3), and doesn't work on galaxy gio (2.2), s3 nor s4 (4.0+)

```
private void setRingTone()
{
try
{
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/testring/a.mp3";
    File file = new File(path);
    Log.v(file.getAbsolutePath(), path);
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "0000");
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/*");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "BY ME");
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
    values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);
    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
    Toast.makeText(this, "success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

The path to the mp3 is valid as I can play it from within same application, this piece of code never throws execption and complete with a success message.

I have these permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_CONFIGURATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just deleted the mp3 uri from ContentResolver before I add it again, and it works pretty well.

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath());
getContentResolver().delete(uri ,null ,null);
Uri newUri = getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```